# HTML/Jquery Removed div's postion occupied by the following div. How to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I have 3 pages. Each page has a parent div of the same class. User can horizontally scroll from one page to another. Also, user can add child divs dynamically into the parent containers. 
Each child has a remove button. On clicking this button the respective child will be removed.

My question is:

1. How to make the child div(s) in parent container on page 2 to occupy the empty position of removed div on page 1 and from page 3 to page 2 simultaneously (in other words continue the chain)?

Related image(Sorry I don't have enough reputation points): https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFVvk.jpg

Please help me. I am novice in all this stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Sample code::

```
   <script>
   //Script of the button to remove a particular div.
   </script>


   //page 1
   <div class= "parent">
   <div id= "child1">
   </div>
   <div id= "child2">
   </div>
   <div id= "child3">
   </div>
    </div>

   //page 2
   <div class= "parent">
   <div id= "child4">
   </div>
   <div id= "child5">
   </div>
   <div id= "child6">
   </div>
   </div>

   //page 3
   <div class= "parent">
   <div id= "child7">
   </div>
   <div id= "child8">
   </div>
   <div id= "child9">
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Post a fidddle at jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: You mean each parent should have three divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something like this is what you are looking for...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6ECz/)

```
$(".remove").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $parents = $(".parent");
    $children = $parents.children("div");
    $children.each( function(i) {
        $parents.eq(Math.floor(i/3)).append($(this));
    });
});
```

---

I know you've already accepted the above code, but the following will require less DOM manipulation (it only moves what it has to)... but this also assumes that every `.parent` (except perhaps the last one) had 3 elements before removing one whereas the above code would fix anything that was messed up prior to the current delete.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6ECz/1/)

```
$(".remove").on("click", function() {
    $parent = $(this).closest(".parent");
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $parent.nextAll(".parent").each( function() {
        $(this).prev(".parent").append($(this).children("div").eq(0));
    });
});
```

Basically, use the first one if you want to make sure that there is always 3 children in each parent up until the last one and you are uncertain that the DOM will be correct before the delete.

Use the second one if you are certain the DOM will be correct before the delete and just want to move only the necessary elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `appendChild` for a parent to adopt a child.

Use it as follows :

`var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0];`

`var child = document.getElementById('child4');`

`parent.appendChild('child');`

OR Simply write :

`document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0].appendChild( document.getElementById('child4'));`

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: When you get elements by classname you get a list of elements. `NodeList` doesn't have `appendChild` in javascript so you'll end up with a javascript error. Also if you did appendChild for all elements of the NodeList, you'd end up with duplicates.

Comment: @smerny : Oh I just forgot to add the index to parent. I have edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: You are still missing quotes around `child4`, still aren't getting the index of `.parent` in the bottom segment of code. This wouldn't also move children from the 3rd page to the 2nd page. This would involve a lot of work, what if an element other than `child3` is removed? some elements may have already been deleted prior to the current item of interest... if you are getting them by ID you would have to keep checking if there is a higher `"child"+index` and figuring out if they need to be moved and where.